# Boolean expression with four operands

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

How can I write a boolean expression which will be true if and only if there is one out of four operands is true? I need the most succinct possible way to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
((A XOR B) XOR (C XOR D)) AND (NOT (A AND B)) AND (NOT (C AND D))
```

The first part

```
((A XOR B) XOR (C XOR D))
```

Works for all cases except three inputs being true, hence the second part.